# Double asterisk in a request mapping

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

What does it mean when double asterisk is present in a request mapping?
For instance

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/", "/welcome**" }, method =
RequestMethod.GET)  public ModelAndView welcomePage() { ...
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Universally speaking asterisks (in wildcard role) mean

`/welcome*` : anything in THIS folder or URL section, that starts with `"/welcome"` and ends before next `"/"` like `/welcomePage`.

`/welcome**` : any URL, that starts with `"/welcome"` including sub-folders and sub-sections of URL pattern like `/welcome/section2/section3/` or `/welcomePage/index`.

`/welcome/*` : any file, folder or section inside welcome (before next `"/"`) like `/welcome/index`.

`/welcome/**` : any files, folders, sections, sub-folders or sub-sections inside welcome.

In other words one asterisk * ends before next `"/"`, two asterisks ** have no limits.

Answer (score 1):

1. [Ant paths](https://ant.apache.org/manual/dirtasks.html)
2. URL mapping ordering. [From Spring Docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-ann-requestmapping-pattern-comparison):

> When a URL matches multiple patterns, a sort is used to find the most
>   specific match.
>
> A pattern with a lower count of URI variables and wild cards is
>   considered more specific. For example /hotels/{hotel}/* has 1 URI
>   variable and 1 wild card and is considered more specific than
>   /hotels/{hotel}/** which as 1 URI variable and 2 wild cards

...

> There are also some additional special rules:
>
> - The default mapping pattern /** is less specific than any other pattern. For example /api/{a}/{b}/{c} is more specific.
> - A prefix pattern such as /public/** is less specific than any other pattern that doesn’t contain double wildcards. For example
>     /public/path3/{a}/{b}/{c} is more specific.

Comment: Then what is the difference in case of using `/welcome**` and `/welcome*`? In both cases a path `/welcome/ftp` or `/welcome/ftp/index` is illegal.

Comment: `**` means zero or more characters, where it can also contain path separator `/`. So I bet it may work for mentioned paths, but `/welcome/**` would be better.