# Spring Boot multiple slashes in path variable

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm trying to do

```
    @GetMapping(value = "/vault/{key}", produces = "application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<VaultEntity> getEntity(
            @RequestHeader HttpHeaders headers, @RequestHeader(name = "X-Vault-Token") String token,
            HttpServletRequest request, @PathVariable(name = "key") String key) {
        log.info(String.format("%s provided token: %s for key %s", headers.getHost(), token, request.getRequestURI()));
        return vaultService.findByKey(request.getRequestURI(), key, token);
    }
```

but I want it to match:

```
/vault/key
/vault/key/key1
/vault/key/key2/key3
```

and so on

I tried regular expression matching but came up with nothing. What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: "key", "key/key1" is key is a dynamic as in like  "test", "test/test1" is this also possible?

Comment: Sort of, it's used to lookup in a table

Comment: You can use the recursive syntax as in [those answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40188743/double-asterisk-in-a-request-mapping).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try like this
**if key is a static**

```
@RequestMapping(value={"/vault/key", "/vault/key/key1", "/vault/key/key1"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<VaultEntity> getEntity(
            @RequestHeader HttpHeaders headers, @RequestHeader(name = "X-Vault-Token") String token,
            HttpServletRequest request, @PathVariable(name = "key") String key) {
        log.info(String.format("%s provided token: %s for key %s", headers.getHost(), token, request.getRequestURI()));
        return vaultService.findByKey(request.getRequestURI(), key, token);
    }
```

**if key is a dynamic**

```
@RequestMapping(value={"/vault/{key}", "/vault/{key}/{key1}", "/vault/{key}/{key1}/{key3}"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<VaultEntity> getEntity(
@PathVariable("key") String key, @PathVariable("key1") String key1, @PathVariable("key3") String key3, @RequestHeader HttpHeaders headers, @RequestHeader(name = "X-Vault-Token") String token,HttpServletRequest request, @PathVariable(name = "key") String key) {
        log.info(String.format("%s provided token: %s for key %s", headers.getHost(), token, request.getRequestURI()));
        return vaultService.findByKey(request.getRequestURI(), key, token);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using regex for the path variable.

See if the below link helps
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-5-mvc-url-matching

Try this -

```
@GetMapping("/vault/**")
@ResponseBody
public void test1(HttpServletRequest req) {
    String path = (String)req.getAttribute(HandlerMapping.PATH_WITHIN_HANDLER_MAPPING_ATTRIBUTE);
    String pathVariable = path.replaceAll("/vault/", "");
    System.out.println(pathVariable); // prints "key" for uri -> /vault/key
                                      // prints "key/key1" for uri -> /vault/key/key1
}
```

Answer (score -1):

pay attention to key1 & key2 they are not required !

```
@GetMapping(value={"/vault/{key}", "/vault/{key}/{key1}", "/vault/{key}/{key1}/{key2}"})
    public ResponseEntity<VaultEntity> getEntity(
            @PathVariable String key,
            @PathVariable(required = false) String key1,
            @PathVariable(required = false) String key2,
            @RequestHeader HttpHeaders headers,
            @RequestHeader(name = "X-Vault-Token") String token,
            HttpServletRequest request) {
        log.info(String.format("%s provided token: %s for key %s", headers.getHost(), token, request.getRequestURI()));
        return vaultService.findByKey(request.getRequestURI(), key, token);
    }
```